# Access list data from tapgesture from image inside viewcell

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a image inside a `ViewCell`, I've added a `TapGestureRecognizer` to the image, now when the user clicks the image I want to Access the data from data `ViewCell`

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

This is simple code to passing data click on ViewCell.

Code UI--

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListItem}" x:Name="lst">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
              <StackLayout>
               <Image Source="abcd" Aspect="AspectFit">
               <Image.GestureRecognizers>
               <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ClickCommand}" 
                      Source={x:Reference lst}}" 
                      CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                 </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                 </Image>
               </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Code ViewModel--

```
 Public Class MainViewModel
{
   Command clickCommand;
    public Command ClickCommand
    {
        get
        {
       return clickCommand ?? (menuTapCommand = new Command<Object>(GetImage));
        }
    }
Private Void GetImage(Object obj)
{
 //Todo
}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the tapGestureRecognizer doesnt have the Source proprety.

Comment: Yes, that was hint but. You can use like this - <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ClickCommand,Source={x:Reference lst}}" /> or

Comment: Now that is resolved, in the viewmodel menuTapCommand is giving me an error, why?

Comment: What is error can you please post the details and if resolve please vote up

Comment: The name ''menuTapCommand" doesnt exist in the current context.

Comment: check you are using same name "menuTapCommand" what  you gave in Viewmodel. It's look like there is no menuTapCommand in viewmodel

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176782/discussion-between-pratius-dubey-and-phill).

Comment: what is the menuTapCommand?
I dont have that in my viewmodel.
Just need to create Command menuTapCommand;
?

Comment: Can you please post the view and viewmodel code with proper exception

Comment: View:
paste.ofcode.org/CnUkyLMDbCb4HUtdS9d6DH

ViewModel:
paste.ofcode.org/YiggZPFkpZyKXKVKTrddwQ

Comment: Doesn't give any exception, when i click in the image nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a `DataTemplate` for a XF ViewCell, the `BindingContext` of that image and the cell itself is the **Data** object. I have a **ViewCell** with an image and a TapGestureRecognizer. It properly executes the `ICommand` in my **Data** object where I have the data needed. You will need an `ICommand` in your data object given to the ListView.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ListItem}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Image Source="abcd">
                        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding ClickCommand}" />
                        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Image>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The **Data** object for your ListView should have the `ICommand`.

```
public class MyDataObject
{
    private Action<string> _openUrl;
    private string _url;

    public MyDataObject(string url, Action<string> openUrl)
    {
        _url = url;
        _openUrl = openUrl;

        ClickCommand = new Command(AccessOtherData);
    }

    public ICommand ClickCommand { get; }

    // Other data properties and such

    private void AccessOtherData()
    {
        // Call method to open _url
        _openUrl(_url);
    }
}
```

Your `ObservableCollection` in your pages ViewModel should have a list of **Data** objects

**ViewModel:**

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public event EventHandler<string> OpenUrl;

    // List filled with the MyDataObject
    public ObservableCollection<MyDataObject> Collection { get; set; }

    private void FillCollection()
    {
        // Create all MyDataObjects here
        // Each object will be created like this
        Collection.Add(new MyDataObject("insert url here", OpenUrlFromObject));
    }

    private void OpenUrlFromObject(string url)
    {
        OpenUrl?.Invoke(this, url); // Subscribe to this event in your Page and open
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, now how can i get the data?
I want to click in the image, get data and them open a url that is on the data.

Comment: If you are wanting the **Data** that is associated with the `MyDataObject`, you have it once the Image is clicked and the `AccessOtherData` method is ran from the command executing. You are in the correct object with the **Data**.

Comment: When you are creating the list of `MyDataObject`, you should be giving the information that will be needed later to each object in the list. Then once your image is clicked, you will have the correct data and you are in **one specific** `MyDataObject`.

Comment: Can give an example please?

Comment: I edited my answer with changes to show the **url** in the data object and propogate that back to your UI in order to open it.

Comment: "Subscribe to this event in your Page and open" who i do that?

Comment: In your **.xaml.cs** of your page where you set your `BindingContext` to your ViewModel, do viewModelInstance.OpenUrl += OpenUrl_EventHandler;. At that point you will have the **Url** passed to your view so you can open it in some form of WebView or another browser.

Comment: Sorry, but i don't understand this logic, i can't get this to work.